# c# WCF SSPI failed during connecting to Windows Service

Tags: wcf, windows-services, sspi

I want to mention that i am new to WCF.

I encountered a problem connecting to a WCF service.

The WCF service was created with netTcpBinding and installed on the server machine as Window Service which is running on specific account (defined in properties). During invoking published method from client computer I get an error with SSPI failed.

If I run Window Service without specific account it works fine.  The problem happens if I add this account. I can't not skip that because service needs that credential to use DirectorySearch.

I investigated that mayby  in .cofig should be set differently.
Maybe:

```
value="serverName:port/service/"
dns value="serverName:port"
dns value="account"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had to pass username into identity.